# 'Request timed out' when accessing port 81

Tags: web-server

How to make port 81 accessible thro' url like http://192.168.1.100:81/ , rite now if i run given url in my browser (client , different machine) then i get error "Couldn' connect to server" "Request timed out".

Comment: We need more information about your environment. What OS is your server running? What webserver are you using ?

Answer (score 2):

You need to open port 81 on your server firewall.

Answer (score 2):

You also need to ensure that IIS/apache or whatever is listening to port 81 as well.